# What's the use for the FUTURE, CHANGES and NOTE comments?

Tags: tags, comments

The brackets-todo extension for the Brackets editor looks by default for the following keywords: `TODO, FIXME, NOTE, FUTURE, CHANGES`

The two first ones are pretty self-explanatory and I've used them for ages. `NOTE` is obviously for a note - but why do we want to keep our `NOTE`s organized? Comments are basically for notes, so it sounds to me like an useless keyword. What's its purpose?

And what is the usual use of the `FUTURE` and `CHANGES` keywords?

Brackets is an editor aimed at web development: html, css, php, js

Comment: it'd be helpful if you mentioned WHICH language you're talking about. keywords on this site?

Comment: Brackets is basically about web development: html, css, js, phpqt

Comment: then you should tag the question with that. don't make us GUESS what you're talking about.